# ¿Para qué sirve PyV8?

Tags: sublimetext3

Me encontré con este curioso paquete en la lista de Sublime y no tengo idea de para que sirva, y si lo puedo remover sin que explote nada.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Probaste googlear antes de preguntar, o... no sé, buscar en https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyV8 por ejemplo?

Comment: Busque pero salen temas relacionados con Emmet, yo queria saber si es independiente de Sublime y que función cumple en este entorno.

Comment: Recomendaría que agregues a la pregunta la información que encontraste, y qué es lo que te interesa saber específicamente de la función en Sublime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dicho paquete, forma parte de la configuración de Sublime Text ya que el lenguaje con el que esta hecho es Python y si te fijas la extensión de dicho archivo es **.py**; si lo desisntalas provocarás el fallo en la instalación de plugins.

Con base en el uso que desde hace años llevo de **Sublime Text** te comento lo siguiente:

- No afecta tenerlo instalado
- Generarás fallos en la instalación de plugins de terceros

Saludos